# Reshape batch of tensors into batch of vectors in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, reshape, dimension

During creating a calculation graph I have a tensor `x` e.g. with shape of `[-1, a, b, c]` and I would like to reshape it into `[-1, a*b*c]`
I tried to do it this way:

```
n = functools.reduce(operator.mul, x.shape[1:], 1)
tf.reshape(x, [-1, n])
```

but I've got an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Dimension'
```

My question is: is there is TensorFlow something to do this operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message tells you, there is a problem with the types. If you create a TensorFlow placeholder, e.g. with

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> x = tf.placeholder(tf.float16, shape=(None, 3,7,4))
```

and call `shape` on it, then the return value is

```
>>> x.shape
TensorShape([Dimension(None), Dimension(3), Dimension(7), Dimension(4)])
```

and each element is a

```
>>> x.shape[1]
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape.Dimension'>
```

i.e. a `Dimension` class of TensorFlow. Naturally, the `operator.mul` function doesn't know what to do with such a type. Luckily, the [`tf.TensorShape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape) has a `as_list()` function, which returns the shape as a list of integers.

```
>>> x.shape.as_list()
[None, 3, 7, 4]
```

With that, you can calculate the number of elements `n`, as you're used to:

```
>>> import functools, operator
>>> n = functools.reduce(operator.mul, x.shape.as_list()[1:], 1)
>>> n 
84
>>> y = tf.reshape(x, [-1, n])
```